# change listview icon JQM

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

```
<ul data-role= listview></ul>
```

in jQuery mobile, the default data-icon of code above is **arrow-r**. Is it possible to change the default data-icon to delete? and is it also possible to make **onclick** function on the icon?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the icon on the LI element by setting the `data-icon`:

```
<ul data-role="listview" >
    <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#">data-icon="delete"</a></li>
    <li data-icon="gear"><a href="#">data-icon="gear"</a></li>
    <li data-icon="info"><a href="#">data-icon="info"</a></li>
    <li data-icon="false"><a href="#">data-icon="false"</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want a click handler just on the icon, you are better off using split buttons. See example here: **http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/listviews/#list-split**

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#">
        <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
        <p>Broken Bells</p></a>
        <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">
        <h2>Warning</h2>
        <p>Hot Chip</p></a>
        <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change all listview items, you can achieve it through two ways.

1. Change default icon on `pagecreate` event, of a specific listview

   ```
   $(document).on("pagecreate", "[data-role=page]", function () {
     $(".selector").listview({ icon:"delete" });
   });
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/db5we/)**
2. Change default icon globally on `mobileinit` event, of all listviews This should be loaded after jQuery js library and before jQuery Mobile js.

   ```
   $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
     $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.icon = "delete";
   });
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/rkc3c/)**